# In a command, is there a way to use argument \sqrt{2} in one place and evaluate it in another

Tags: macros

I'm trying to use a command to plot points on a line:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\newcommand{\markPoint}[1]{
    \tkzDefPoint(#1,0){A}
    \tkzDrawPoint(A)
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](A){\(#1\)}}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmin=-3, xmax=5]
        \tkzDrawX[noticks]
        \markPoint{\sqrt{2}}    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I have no problem with values like `1` but values like `\sqrt{2}` don't work and I'm wondering if there is a way of evaluating using `\sqrt` because if I have to remove the `\` then I wouldn't be able to use the same argument for the label.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

You can arrange the value of `\sqrt` to be whatever is needed in each context

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tkz-fct}

\newcommand{\markPoint}[1]{%
\let\savedsqrt\sqrt
\def\sqrt##1{sqrt(##1)}%
\let\savedfrac\frac
\def\frac##1##2{(##1)/(##2)}%
    \tkzDefPoint(#1,0){A}%
\let\sqrt\savedsqrt
\let\frac\savedfrac
    \tkzDrawPoint(A)
    \tkzLabelPoint[below](A){\(#1\)}%
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \tkzInit[xmin=-3, xmax=5]
        \tkzDrawX[noticks]
        \markPoint{\sqrt{2}}    
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You will get my upvote if you make `\sqrt[3]{2}` translate to `pow(2,1/3)`. (Note also that `\tkzDefPoint...` makes things global, so you could use `\begingroup...\endgroup` around it, so you won't need `\savedsqrt`.)

Comment: I'm not sure what the two ## do. Could you explain that?
And another question, using this solution, I would have to detect if the input is a square root or a cubic root or even a fraction, am I right? Is there a way of evaluating all of these inputs in a "simple" way?

Comment: @Concept7 its a nested definition so `#1` refers to the argument passed in (`\sqrt{2}` here but `##1` is the argument of the command being defined (`2` here)

Comment: @Concept7 you wouldn't need to detect what the input was but you would need to add suitable definitions for all the forms that you might use.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've done the definition for fractions (basically a copy of your solution with different names and the ##1##2) and it works but only when I comment the first part (your solution for sqrt). Is there something I have to add for them to work together? (I'm so sorry if I'm being inconvenient)

Comment: @Concept7 I'll ad the frac, what do you want in the expression form (#1) / (#2) ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle ok! Now I understand how multiple definitions work! I was doing it as if they were separate blocks and defining the point twice! Thank you so much!!